# IBM Watson Api Visual Recognition Error

Tags: java, android, watson

I am trying to implement Watson API for visual recognition. I encounter the following error message:

[image: Error message]

Here is the code:

```
public class VisualRecognizer {
private VisualRecognition service;

public VisualRecognizer() {
    this.service = new VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_20);
    this.service.setApiKey("ourkey");
    this.service.setEndPoint("https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api");
}

public String classifyImage(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    ClassifyOptions classifyOptions = new ClassifyOptions.Builder()
            .imagesFile(imageStream)
            .build();
    ClassifiedImages result = service.classify(classifyOptions).execute();
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please mention a file name.

```
ClassifyOptions classifyOptions = new ClassifyOptions.Builder()
            .imagesFile(imageStream).imagesFilename("xyz.jpg")
            .build();
```

For me it worked